# How to delete (unlink) a file from directory, when its name starting with a dot (.) but its not a hidden file?

Tags: php, filenames, unlink

I'd like to delete (unlink) files from a directory like this: `.name.ico` , but the "name" can be anything else. I tried the `.*.ico` like this:

```php
unlink("dir1/dir2/.*.ico");
```

but it is not successfull.

If in the code I write the correct filename like this:

```php
unlink("dir1/dir2/.name.ico");
```

the procedure is succesfull! But I dont know always what is the "name" exactly, I have to masked "name" to "*"

I would like to ask for help in resolving this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471989/using-a-wildcard-in-php-unlink

Comment: Thank you for this good solution!

Answer (score 0):

I used this as a solution:

```
$icofilename = (glob("dir1/dir2/.*.ico"));
unlink($icofilename[1]);
```